# Xamarin Forms - ListView: IsVisible binding to an invisible item inside a list view is not working after scrolling to show that item

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, prism

**Hello,**

I'm running into very annoying problem, what I need is simple but I'm getting an unexpected problem, here is what I'm trying to do:

I have a listview containing 2 labels in the ViewCell, both labels show same field but the difference is that the first is visible and the font is normal and the second is invisible and the font is bold, what I wanted to do is when I click on the item to change the property named: "Selected" from false to true and vise versa so that the bold label show/hide to inform the user that the item is selected.

In order to achieve this I wrote my code and I deploy the simple app on my android device and it worked like a charm, but after that I noticed that if I scroll the listview to an item that was not shown on the screen and click on that item, the first normal label disappeared which is an expected behavior **but the second bold label doesn't shown**

**The following is my code:**

**testVisibilityProblem.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CPALMSStandardsViewer;assembly=CPALMSStandardsViewer"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CPALMSStandardsViewer.Converters"
             xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:CPALMSStandardsViewer.Helper"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="CPALMSStandardsViewer.Views.testVisibilityProblem">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Margin="10,0,10,0"
                  BackgroundColor="White"
                  SeparatorColor="Gray"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CustomEntities}"
                  VerticalOptions="Fill"
                  SelectionMode="None"
                  HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" 
                                          Command="{Binding SelectCustomEntity}"
                                          EventArgsConverter="{converters:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Label  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={Helpers:InverseBoolConverter}}"></Label>
                            <Label  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**testVisibilityProblemViewModel.cs**

```
using CPALMSStandardsViewer.Models;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace CPALMSStandardsViewer.ViewModels
{
    public class testVisibilityProblemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CustomEntity> CustomEntities { get; set; }

        public testVisibilityProblemViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Test Visibility Problem!";
            CustomEntities = new ObservableCollection<CustomEntity>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                CustomEntities.Add(new CustomEntity() { Name = "Item " + i, IsSelected = false });

            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand<CustomEntity> _SelectCustomEntity;
        public DelegateCommand<CustomEntity> SelectCustomEntity => _SelectCustomEntity ?? (_SelectCustomEntity = new DelegateCommand<CustomEntity>(ExecuteSelectCustomEntityCommand));

        private void ExecuteSelectCustomEntityCommand(CustomEntity paramData)
        {
            paramData.IsSelected = !paramData.IsSelected;
        }


    }
}
```

**CustomEntity.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
namespace CPALMSStandardsViewer.Models
{
    public class CustomEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        private bool _IsSelected;
        public bool IsSelected { get { return _IsSelected; } set { _IsSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

I searched a lot concerning this problem and all what I found is something related to the OnPropertyChanged(), someone miss use the observable collection, other one miss the use of OnPropertyChanged(), other one used it in wrong way...

But my problem is different, it's not about binding because the top items worked as expected and also as I already mentioned the first label becomes hidden which is expected, my problem is that when you turn the IsVisible from false to true for an item that was not rendered on the screen, it simply not working.

I may know the problem but I tried a lot to get it solved but none of the solutions I tried work for me.

Please note that UWP worked as expected, my problem is on android platform.

Please HELP!

Comment: You can try to set the caching strategy to `RecycleElement` to zero-in the problem. `RecycleElement` will create the viewcell and hence should fire all the property changes. If it works, you can raise a bug on xamarin forms github

Comment: @shanranm thanks for your reply, I tried it but it didn't work :(

Comment: have you debug to see if trigger ExecuteSelectCustomEntityCommand when you click the listview second click ？

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, yes I did and it works normally and the proof of this is that the first label visibility turned to false.

Comment: I raised this issue as a bug to xamarin forms github: "https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6683"